# Adding counted words together

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the words in a string and add all of them together to get the average and total amount of words

```
words = input("Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: ")
wordlist = words.split()
count = 0
while words != "":
    words = input("Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: ")
    for i in wordlist:
        count += len(words.split())
        if count > 0:
            count += 1
print("There were " +str(count)+ " words")
```

Comment: Why are you needing to check `count > 0`?

Comment: ill be honest I was just putting random things together to see if it will work

Comment: Walk through your logic by-hand. For example, you have an initial `wordlist` , but you started `count = 0`... Did you want to count the initial words you typed or not?

Comment: I want to count each word the user inputs until they stop inputting anymore words

Comment: What is your question? You have just described your goal. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). You need to describe the _specific_ problem you're having with your code and ask a question about that problem. Welcome to SO!

Comment: We understand you want to count each word, but "putting random things" doesnt explain _why_ you thought that'd work.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you enter any word, then `count > 0` will be true, and you'd double-count it after using `len()`
2. You are forgetting to count the intial input

I suggest using a while loop. And if you want the average of the words, you'll need to actually store them, not just count them.

```
all_words = []
while True:
    line = input('Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: ')
    if not line:
        break
    all_words.extend(line.split())

average = 0  # TODO
print('There are {} words with average length {}'.format(len(all_words), average))
```

Unclear what average you want, though... Average length of individual word? Average number of words per loop?

If the latter, use `all_words.append(line.split())`, then `total_words = sum(len(x) for x in all_words)`

Comment: the average word length

Comment: `average = sum(len(x) for x in all_words) / len(all_words)`

Comment: so I'm close but when I put in a certain amount of words for the repeated question it's one word short

Comment: You'd need to give an example of what you're typing. It seems to work fine from my limited testing

Comment: Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: cat
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: dog
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: ball
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: apple
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: egg
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: fruit
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: 
There are 5 words with average length 4.0

Comment: well that just looks like a mess but that's what I'm getting and I typed cat, dog, ball, apple, egg, and fruit

Comment: Hmm. I just tried it with the code in my answer, and I get `There are 6 words with average length 3.8333333333333335`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with functional style, and then you get a pretty output as well :)

```py
def words(fn):
  return [len(ws.split())] + words(fn) if (ws := fn()) else []

def statistics(words):
  return {
    'avg': sum(words) / len(words),
    'sum': sum(words),
  }

print(statistics(words(lambda: input('Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: '))))
```

Output:

```
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: Hello my friend
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: You wanna learn python
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: Python is good for many thing
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: Also if you wanna do functional programming
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop: If you dont like functional programming you can still do python
Enter a line of words, press Enter to stop:
{'avg': 6.2, 'sum': 31}
```